# Why can't Update Manager find any updates?

Tags: updates, update-manager

My update manager does not find any updates. It does not crash or anything, but no update for my ubuntu, except for the PPAs. At first I thought there really was no update out there, but now it has been more than a month since my last update. What is wrong here?

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

(I also tried the MainServers, but still nothing.)

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1162185/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You must have the `-updates` and `-security` repositories set!

You aren't getting any updates because they go into the `precise-updates` and `precise-security` repositories, and you only have the main `precise` repository in your *sources.list!*

- Set up Software Sources this way:

  [image]
- Or if you want to manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, add the following two lines:

  ```
  deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
  ```